# How do I associate files with the xml that references them in Python?

Tags: python, elementtree

I have two directories: assets and metadata.
The assets directory has a bunch of video files while the metadata directory has a bunch of existing xml files.

I want to calculate checksums and grab file sizes of all the assets and put them in the metadata that matches them. Those fields already exist, but are empty.

I'm parsing with element tree and am already able to get the file sizes and checksums, but I'm not sure how to get them into the right metadata.  The video files are named with an ID that is also present in the metadata and is already assigned to the variable 'id', so I thought I could associate them like this:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.mov"):
    if file == (id + '.mov'):
        video_filename = file
    elif video_filename != (id + '.mov'): 
        print(id, 'There is no video file associated with that ID!!!')
```

When I run the script, and it sees one of the other files first, I get the else if condition above.

How do I check that I have the correct video file for the xml and that the data is going into the right xml file?

Comment: If you're looking for the file that has a name that matches `(id + '.mov')`, then you're looking for a file with a specific name, right?  So why go through all of the files in the directory when you can just reference that one file directly by name?

Comment: Because I have multiple .xmls and multiple .movs.  I want to be able to run the script once and process all the files in the directory.

Comment: Then you need different logic.  You should be extracting the `id` from the filename.  You shouldn't have to go through all of the files in a directory for every `id`.  But you COULD do that.  If one of the files matches, then your code will work as it exists.  So then just don't do anything if the filename doesn't match...just remove your `elif` case (which, btw, could be just `else:`.

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate over all the movie files and make a dictionary of {id:filepath} pairs.
- Iterate over the xml files, for each metadata get the ID of its movie

  - and use that ID with the dictionary to look up the path to the correct movie file
  - process the movie file
  - put the new info in the metadata.